# module 'cv2' has no attribute "TrackerCSRT_create' on Nvidia Xavier

Tags: python, opencv

We have tried with various version of opencv as well as opencv-contrib-python.
But it's giving same error. Same program works well in windows OS.

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute "TrackerCSRT_create'

How to resolve this to run on Nvidia Xavier board?

Versions we are using currently

- opencv-python 4.5.1.48
- opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.62

Comment: why do you think that identifier exists? point to a source please. check that you typed the name correctly. compare with the official documentation. I'm sure you are missing the letters `e` and `r`.

Comment: I apologize, it is 'TrackerCSRT_create'
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute "TrackerCSRT_create'

Comment: you must have installed **exactly one** of both modules. they can't both be installed at the same time. remove both first, then install the one you want. this is likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

since opencv 4.4 (or so) some trackers were moved to a `legacy` module:

```
>>> help(cv2.legacy)
Help on module cv2.legacy in cv2:

NAME
    cv2.legacy

FUNCTIONS
    MultiTracker_create(...)
        MultiTracker_create() -> retval
        .   * \brief Returns a pointer to a new instance of MultiTracker

    TrackerBoosting_create(...)
        TrackerBoosting_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor
        .       @param parameters BOOSTING parameters TrackerBoosting::Params

    TrackerCSRT_create(...)
        TrackerCSRT_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor
        .     @param parameters CSRT parameters TrackerCSRT::Params

    TrackerKCF_create(...)
        TrackerKCF_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor
        .     @param parameters KCF parameters TrackerKCF::Params

    TrackerMIL_create(...)
        TrackerMIL_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor
        .       @param parameters MIL parameters TrackerMIL::Params

    TrackerMOSSE_create(...)
        TrackerMOSSE_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor

    TrackerMedianFlow_create(...)
        TrackerMedianFlow_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor
        .       @param parameters Median Flow parameters TrackerMedianFlow::Params

    TrackerTLD_create(...)
        TrackerTLD_create() -> retval
        .   @brief Constructor
        .       @param parameters TLD parameters TrackerTLD::Params

    upgradeTrackingAPI(...)
        upgradeTrackingAPI(legacy_tracker) -> retval
```

so, the way to create one is:

```
cv2.legacy.TrackerCSRT_create()
```

(you still need `opencv-contrib-python` !)

((and, if you installed `opencv-python` before, you need to uninstall that, else it will "shadow" the other, both have a `cv2.so`, and python will only load one of them ...))

Comment: We have tried with Opencv-contrib-python version 4.5.5.62 (uninstalled both Opencv-python and Opencv-contrib-python, and then had a clean installation of Opencv-contrib-python). 
Used cv2.legacy.TrackerCSRT_create(), but still it says no module named 'legacy'
The same thing works fine in windows.

Comment: unfortunately i cant help with your local installation problem. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d8f/classcv_1_1legacy_1_1TrackerCSRT.html#a3c5ae96951e36434274d8c616de8850e