# module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerCSRT_create'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, attributeerror, tracker

I try to run the following code, but there is an AttributeError. I have tried everything but anything works. If anyone has any idea feel free to tell me.

--

```
import cv2
import time
import math

p1 = 530
p2 = 300

xs = []
ys = []

video = cv2.VideoCapture("footvolleyball.mp4")
# Carga el rastreador
tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

# Lee el primer cuadro del video
check, img = video.read()

# Selecciona el campo delimitador en la imagen
bbox = cv2.selectROI("rastreando", img, False)

# Inicializa el rastreador en la imagen y el campo delimitador
tracker.init(img, bbox)

def goal_track(img, bbox):
    x, y, w, h = int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])
    c1 = x + int(w / 2)
    c2 = y + int(h / 2)
    cv2.circle(img, (c1, c2), 2, (0, 0, 255), 5)

    cv2.circle(img, (int(p1), int(p2)), 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    dist = math.sqrt(((c1 - p1) ** 2) + (c2 - p2) ** 2)
    print(dist)

    if dist <= 20:
        cv2.putText(img, "Objetivo", (300, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    xs.append(c1)
    ys.append(c2)

    for i in range(len(xs) - 1):
        cv2.circle(img, (xs[i], ys[i]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 5)

def drawBox(img, bbox):
    x, y, w, h = int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), ((x + w), (y + h)), (255, 0, 255), 3, 1)
    cv2.putText(img, "Rastreando", (75, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

while True:
    check, img = video.read()   

    success, bbox = tracker.update(img)

    if success:
        drawBox(img, bbox)
        goal_track(img, bbox)
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "Perdido", (75, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("resultado", img)
            
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)

    if key == 32:
        print("¡Alto!")
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyALLwindows()
```

- 

**Output:**

```
PS C:\Users\danny\OneDrive\Documentos\programacion\Proyecto 119> & C:/Users/danny/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.12.exe "c:/Users/danny/OneDrive/Documentos/programacion/Proyecto 119/obj_trk_final.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\danny\OneDrive\Documentos\programacion\Proyecto 119\obj_trk_final.py", line 13, in <module>
    tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerCSRT_create'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module 'cv2' has no attribute "TrackerCSRT\_create' on Nvidia Xavier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768356/module-cv2-has-no-attribute-trackercsrt-create-on-nvidia-xavier)